# DSL for Makefile generation for dotfiles using symlinks

Tags: beginner, perl, makefile

As I explain in my [rant](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/07/12/plink-rant/), I have been searching for a replacement to hand-crafted POSIX-`make`-compatible makefiles to manage my dotfiles (which use symlinks). I decided the simplest thing to do would be to roll my own.

Requirements:

- written in a language likely to be immediately available on major platforms (I have chosen Perl)
- no other external dependencies (installation for dotfiles should be a clone-and-run process)
- can live next to/as a submodule of a dotfiles repository

For this I developed [Plink](https://github.com/benknoble/plink). I will quote the specification from the README, and omit the same from the POD in my Perl code. Full details at the link above, including test code.

## DESCRIPTION

The **Plink** module provides an implementation of the Plink language, a DSL
built to describe dotfiles via symlinks. The language is a strict superset of
make(1); implementations produce (POSIX) makefiles for use. It is important to
note that Plink only guarantees that generated code is POSIX-compatible.
User-written code may use GNU make or other non-portable features. What follows
is the canonical specification of the Plink language.

### Plink Specification

Plink is superset of POSIX make. It defines four (4) new syntaxes with semantic
meaning.

Plink also defines a header and footer.

A conforming implementation transforms the input file (or STDIN) as specified by the syntaxes. All lines not participating in one of these syntaxes, in addition to `#` comments, are copied verbatim (this includes blank lines). The output is written to a file named by the environment variable `PLINK_OUTPUT`, or `Makefile` if unset.

See `t/test.plink` for an example Plink file, and `t/expected.mk` for its
output.

#### Square Brackets `[ prerequisites ]`

Any line like

```
target names [ prerequisites ] ...
```

will be transformed to

```
target names: $MAKEFILE prerequisites ...
```

`$MAKEFILE` denotes the name of the generated filename.  The spaces around
`[]` are not *required*, but often recommended. `...` may make use of any the
bang-syntaxes.

#### Bang and Double-bang `!` `!!`

Lines like

```
target ! commands
```

will be transformed to

```
target:
<TAB>commands
```

The list `commands` lasts to the end of the line. `commands` will be indented
by one tab, as make requires.

Similarly, lines like

```
target !!
commands
on more lines
!!
```

become

```
target:
<TAB>commands
<TAB>on more lines
```

The list `commands` lasts until the line containing *exactly* `!!`. Commands
will be tab-indented.

#### Symlink (Fat-arrow) `<=`

The meat of the DSL. Lines like

```
link_in_home <= dotfile_under_$(LINKS)
```

Become part of a mapping. The output creates dependencies of the form

```
$(HOME)/link_in_home: $(LINKS)dotfile_under_$(LINKS)
```

for each fat-arrow, and also gives each the recipe

```
if test -e $@ ; then rm -rf $@ ; fi
ln -s $$(realpath $?) $@
@echo $@ '->' $$(realpath $?)
```

which creates the link. Finally, a target named `symlink` is provided which
depends on all the `link_in_home`s provided: it is considered the public API
for any make target that wishes to depend on symlink-generation.

Dotfiles are files under the make macro `$(LINKS)`. Due to the generation rule,
if `$(LINKS)` is not set, the current directory is used. This can be useful to
put all dotfiles under a directory named, e.g., `dots`. Then you want to
include a line in your Plink file like

```
LINKS = dots/
```

(note the trailing slash).

The use of the macro `SYMLINKS` is considered a Plink implementation detail and
is subject to change; users who set `SYMLINKS` or depend on it's effects are
invoking undefined behavior.

#### Header

The Plink header consists of

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES:
```

#### Footer

The Plink footer consists of the symlink target implementation and the
following:

```
MAKEFILE: INPUT
<TAB>$$(realpath $?)
```

`MAKEFILE` refers to the generated output, and `INPUT` to the Plink file used
as input.

## METHODS

*plink* *$infname*, *$outfname*

Implements the Plink specification, transforming the file named `infname` to
`outfname`. Handles for STDIN and STDOUT are accepted, though STDIN has the
side-effect that the Makefile rules now depend on the literal file `STDIN`.
Similarly, STDOUT breaks the rule to make the generated Makefile.

## CODE

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl

package Plink v1.0.0;

use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use open ':locale';
# implicit with
# use v5.10;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(plink);

main() unless caller(0);

sub trim {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    return $string;
}

sub process_deps {
    my ($line, $outfname) = @_;
    return $line if $line =~ /^#/;
    my ($target, $deps, $rest) = $line =~ m{^
        (.+)        # target
        \[(.*)\]    # dependencies
        (.*)        # anything else
    $}x;
    return $line unless $target;
    $target = trim $target;
    $rest = trim $rest;
    my @deps = grep(!/^\s*$/, map { trim $_ } (split /\s+/, $deps));
    return "$target: $outfname @deps $rest\n";
}

sub process_bang {
    my ($line, $outfname) = @_;
    $line = process_deps($line, $outfname);
    my ($target, $rest) = $line =~ m{^
        ([^!]+)    # target
        !          # bang
        ([^!]+)    # rest
    $}x;
    return unless $target;
    $rest = trim $rest;
    $target = trim $target;
    unless ($target =~ /:/) {
        $target = "$target:"
    }
    return <<TARGET;
$target
\t$rest
TARGET
}

sub print_header {
    my $out = shift;
    print $out <<HEADER;
SHELL = /bin/sh
.SUFFIXES:

HEADER
}

sub print_footer {
    my ($out, $outfname, $infname) = @_;
    print $out <<FOOTER;
# symlink: ensure symlinks created
symlink: $outfname \$(SYMLINKS)

\$(SYMLINKS):
\tif test -e \$@ ; then rm -rf \$@ ; fi
\tln -s \$\$(realpath \$?) \$@
\t\@echo \$@ '->' \$\$(realpath \$?)

$outfname: $infname
\t\$\$(realpath \$?)
FOOTER
}

sub process_lines {
    my ($in, $out, $outfname) = @_;
    my %links;

    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        next if ($line =~ m/^#!|^!!$/);
        # skip comments, no preprocessing
        if ($line =~ m/^#/) {
            print $out $line;
        }
        # !!
        elsif ($line =~ m/!!/) {
            (my $target = process_deps($line, $outfname)) =~ s/!!\s*$//;
            $target = trim $target;
            unless ($target =~ /:/) {
                $target = "$target:"
            }
            print $out "$target\n";
            while (my $sub_line = <$in>) {
                last if $sub_line =~ /!!/;
                print $out "\t$sub_line";
            }
        }
        # !
        elsif ($line =~ m/!/) {
            print $out process_bang($line, $outfname);
        }
        # <=
        elsif ($line =~ m/<=/) {
            my ($link, $dotfile) = map { trim $_ } split /<=/, $line;
            $links{$link} = $dotfile;
        }
        else {
            print $out process_deps($line, $outfname);
        }
    }

    return %links;
}

sub print_links {
    my ($out, %links) = @_;
    print $out "SYMLINKS = \\\n";
    # print %links
    for my $link (sort keys %links) {
        print $out "\$(HOME)/$link \\\n";
    }
    print $out "\n\n";

    for my $link (sort keys %links) {
        print $out "\$(HOME)/$link: \$(LINKS)$links{$link}\n";
    }
    print $out "\n";
}

sub get_in {
    my $infname = shift;
    if ($infname eq \*STDIN) {
        return ($infname, 'STDIN');
    }
    else {
        open(my $in, '<', $infname);
        return ($in, $infname);
    }
}

sub get_out {
    my $outfname = shift;
    if ($outfname eq \*STDOUT) {
        return ($outfname, 'STDOUT');
    }
    else {
        open(my $out, '>', $outfname);
        return ($out, $outfname);
    }
}

sub plink {
    my ($infname, $outfname) = @_;
    my ($in, $out);
    ($in, $infname) = get_in $infname;
    ($out, $outfname) = get_out $outfname;

    print_header $out;
    my %links = process_lines $in, $out, $outfname;
    print_links $out, %links;
    print_footer $out, $outfname, $infname;

    close($out);
    close($in);
}

sub main {
    my $output = $ENV{PLINK_OUTPUT} // 'Makefile';
    my $input = shift @ARGV // \*STDIN;
    plink $input, $output;
}

# return true
1;
```

Comment: in a couple of places you check for emptiness before calling `trim` (which returns an empty value if the input is only whitespace), and then process the possibly-empty value as normal.  Is that intended?

Comment: It should be—trimming `rest`, it doesnt matter if its empty (it’s an optional part, and may not be there to begin with). If youre referring to trimming `target`, i hadnt thought about that. I dont do a whole lot of error checking. Garbage in, garbage out?